# Monitor updates MongoDB databases in realtime

Tags: c#, mongodb

I look for getting an update notification like inserting data in my MongoDB Database.
I find MongoRiver.NET Library ([Link](https://github.com/kspearrin/MongoRiver.NET)) that can help using oplog, So I try with this code, but it give me Exceptions

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MainAsync(args).Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        string uri = "mongodb://Host:27017/Bourse";
        var client = new MongoClient(uri);
        var db = client.GetDatabase("Bourse");
        var col = db.GetCollection<BOSBourse>("Symbole");

        var tailer = new Tailer(client);
        IOutlet outlet = new BOSBourse();
        var stream = new Stream(tailer, outlet);
        Oplog lastOplog = await tailer.GetMostRecentOplog();
        await stream.RunForever(lastOplog);

    }

    private async Task RunStream(Stream stream, Oplog startOplog)
    {
        var task = stream.RunForever(startOplog);
        await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(5000));
        stream.Stop();
    }

    class BOSBourse : IOutlet
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Double Price { get; set; }

        public void UpdateOptime(BsonTimestamp timestamp)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Insert(string databaseName, string collectionName, BsonDocument insertedDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Update(string databaseName, string collectionName, BsonDocument filterDocument, BsonDocument updatedDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Delete(string databaseName, string collectionName, BsonDocument filterDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CreateIndex(string databaseName, string collectionName, BsonDocument indexDocument, BsonDocument optionsDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DeleteIndex(string databaseName, string collectionName, string indexName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void CreateCollection(string databaseName, string collectionName, BsonDocument optionsDocument)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void RenameCollection(string databaseName, string collectionName, string newCollectionName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DeleteCollection(string databaseName, string collectionName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void DeleteDatabase(string databaseName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives me Exceptions:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   MongoRiver.MongoRiverException: Mongo client is not configured as a
>   replica set    at MongoRiver.Tailer..ctor(IMongoClient client,
>   MongoCollectionSettings oplogCollectionSettings, String
>   oplogCollectionName)

Even after I add to the code, I get the same Exception

```
string uri = "mongodb://Host:27017/?safe=true&connect=replicaset";
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format

Comment: Your connection string in plainly wrong and lacks the replset option.

Comment: how can I use replset on ubuntu VM on Azure

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution, i solved my problom do like the this

```
MongoConnectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs1";
```

please, try it

Comment: Please provide bit more information. Why that is the solution and explanation will be good.

Comment: look at  exception info, "System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MongoRiver.MongoRiverException: Mongo client is not configured as a replica set at "   ?replicaSet=rs1 just set the replica set  value